# Ruby on rails - reinitialize classes during page refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in my app/crap folder, I have two ruby files that contain classes. However, when I make changes to one of them, I have to stop Webrick and restart it because my changes don't take effect on the fly.

Is there any way I can make it do this so that it always refreshes everything when it's running in development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All constants under `app/` are autoloaded by default [[1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)].
Also, in development mode you should have this in your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

That way, every file under `app/` should be reloaded automatically.

Also make sure your classes follow the autoloading convention, i.e. are not namespaced (e.g. `Crap::DogCrap` should be `DogCrap` instead). This apparently applies if you have a `app/crap.rb` file that does not define the module `Crap` [[2](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382)].

Comment: Thanks! Going to implement this now.